# google colabでsatsearchがうまくインストールできない

Tags: python

google colabにて
!pip install satsearchを実行したところ以下のようになりうまくいきません。
これに関して解決策がありましたら、ご教示願います。
[image: 以下のようになりました]

Comment: PyPIで検索しても見つからないので名前を間違えているか、何かのローカルなモジュールなのでは？ [0 projects for "satsearch" もしかして'selsearch'ですか？](https://pypi.org/search/?q=satsearch&o=), [satsearch/pysatsearch](https://github.com/satsearch/pysatsearch), [sat-utils/sat-search](https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-search), [sat-search 0.3.0](https://pypi.org/project/sat-search/)

Comment: このモジュール（satsearch）をどう使おうとしていますか？何か他の人が書いたコードを写経しているなどでしたら元のコードを教えてもらえると何か回答できるかもしれません。（現状ですと「うまくインストールできない」ではなく、そのようなモジュールは存在しないのでは？としか分かりません）

Answer (score 1):

おそらく`install`時に指定する名前と、`import`時に指定する名前が違うパッケージ/ライブラリなのでは？
[sat-utils/sat-search](https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-search)

> ```
> $ pip install sat-search
> ```

[sat-search/tutorial-1.ipynb](https://github.com/sat-utils/sat-search/blob/master/tutorial-1.ipynb)

> ```
> from satsearch import Search
> ```

google colab で試したところでは、以下のような結果になります。
[image: sat-search結果]